# jquery: delay() + window.location?

Tags: jquery, location, redirect, delay

I know that we can delay the url redirection easily with plain `javascript` below,

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';}, 2000 );
```

what if I want to use `jQuery`'s `delay()`?

```
$(window.location).delay(4000).attr('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com/');// fail to work!
```

Any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer: **don't** use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) or attempt to, it's a round-about really non-sensical way to get what you're after, since it's [just calling `setTimeout()` underneath](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue.js#L83).

It wasn't designed for this at all (it's for queuing, and then *primarily* for animations), and you're trying to use the location in a [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) wrapper (which is *trying* to use it as a selector), which is also wrong.

Use jQuery (or any other abstraction layer, in any language) **when it makes sense to do so**, it definitely makes no sense here, use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), save yourself the confusion and the client the CPU cost.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not the delay. `$(window.location).attr('href','http://stackoverflow.com/')` wouldn't work either, because href simply isn't an *attribute* of window.location because window.location isn't a DOM node at all.

Comment: @Nick There are not that many problems... if there was a jQuery function that assigns to window.location.href, it would be perfectly valid to put it into the animation chain.

Comment: That's not a valid selector, it's not a DOM element, that isn't an attribute, `.delay()` doesn't work on non-queued functions, and it's just an overall bad way to go about it...yes there are more problems here.